# ASP.NET: Custom subtags

Tags: .net, asp.net, user-controls

Can I develop a control which allows me to do something like this:

```
<MyRadioList>
  <MyRadioButton/>
  <MyRadioButtonWithInfoButton/>
  <MyRadioButton/>
  <MyRadioButtonWithBlueColor/>
</MyRadioList>
```

That is, I can place my own control-tags inside my radio list.

Can it be done with templated user controls?

Answer (score -1):

Create a new RadioList control by extending the built-in one.  Same for the ListItem object, too.  You don't need a template for this situation.

Comment: I cannot extend ListItem because it is a sealed class

Comment: In seeing that ListItem is a sealed class, I'm sure you ran across the ListItemControlBuilder which is not sealed and is extendable.